# Unable to get the same output from a python telegram bot between 2 linux computers

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, telegram

I have a python telegram bot running on my laptop. I am trying to run the same script on my Raspberry Pi4 but i am getting an warning message when I try to run it which isnt happening on the laptop. I am using python 3.9 on both systems and I have installed the same packages.

On the laptop this works fine, however when I ssh to the Pi to run it I get the warning below, when running direct from command line and through vscode ssh.

This is the warning message 'RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Bot.send_message' was never awaited
bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=f'{message}')
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback'

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
#  Telegram bot practice
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib import request
import telegram
import json


chat_id = '********'
token = '***********************************'
bot = telegram.Bot(token=token)


def send_message(message):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=f'{message}')

send_message('hey there')
```

Comment: Warnings are not errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now have it working, I imported asyncio and used asyncio.run for the sending of the message.

I still have no idea why i had this issue on one system and not the oter buy either way it is now working.

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib import request
import telegram
import json
import asyncio

chat_id = '********'
token = '***********************************'
bot = telegram.Bot(token=token)


async def send_message(message):
      bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=f'{message}')

asyncio.run(send_message('hey there'))
```